# Change the page title if a data attribute is found

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts, custom-data-attribute

I'm working on an userscript for a website. Would it be possible to change the title of the site if it finds a certain data attribute?

This is what I currently have:

```
if ($(document.attr('data-class="car"')) {
    $("title").text('*Car found!*');
}
```

Comment: Double check those parentheses...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that AJAX is involved, in which case you can use:

```
var titleCheckTimer = setInterval (checkAndChangeTitle, 333);

function checkAndChangeTitle () {
    if ($('[data-class="car"]').length) {
        document.title = "*Car found!*";

        clearInterval (titleCheckTimer);
    }
}
```

(This also works on static pages as well.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
if ($('[data-class="car"]').length > 0) {
    $('title').text('Car found!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### jQuery

```
if($(document).hasAttribute('data-class'))
    $('title').text('Car found!');
```

or

#### Simple JavaScript code

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName('title');    
if (document.hasAttribute('data-class'))
    title[0].innerHTML = 'Car found!';
```

Comment: A jQuery collection doesn't have a `hasAttribute` member.